# Next line executing despite using async/await

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, readline

I am trying to make a function resolve a promise before reading in subsequent lines.
What I expect is:

```
START
promise resolved
line1
line2
line3
etc ...
```

However, what I am getting is that all my lines are being read before the promise is resolved

```
START
line1
line2
line3
promise resolved
```

I run `npm index.js < input.txt`, which contains:

```
START
line1
line2
line3
```

I have the following main function that reads in lines.

```
marker = true
rl.on("line", async (line: string) => {
  console.log(line);
  if (marker) {
    if (line === "START") {
      // call API and wait for data to return before executing other lines in the file
      let data = await getData();
      console.log("Promise resolved");
    }
    marker = false;
  } else {
    // read subsequent lines
  }
});
```

This is the function I'm calling to get results from my API

```
const async getData = (): Promise<any> => {
  let response = null;
  const p = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      response = await axios.get(
        // url and parameter information here
      );
    } catch (ex) {
      response = null;
      // error
      console.log(ex);
      reject(ex);
    }
    if (response) {
      // success
      const json = response.data;
      resolve(json);
    }
  });
  return p;
};
```

Comment: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` with an `await` inside the executor is almost always an anti-pattern - but anyway, where is `line 1` `line 2` etc output in your code? the issue is likely to be that you think each callback to `rl.on("line", async (line: string) => {` would wait for the previous to complete, which it wouldn't

Comment: @JaromandaX I run my code using npm index.js < inputfile.txt.

inputfile.txt contains:
line1
line2
line3

which is printed at the start of each line using: console.log(line);

Comment: so, the lines in the file are line1 line2 etc ... no line that is just `START` so the `promise resolved` can never be logged either ... which would actually be `Promise resolved` - so your output doesn't make sense given your code

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for clarifying. I updated my post to include the contents of the input.txt file which was ran, the main point is I'm dont get why the line ```let data = await getData();``` is not waiting for the promise to return before executing subsequent lines.

Comment: OK, now that you cleared that up, as I said earlier, each call to `async (line: string) => {` won't "wait" for the previous to complete its asynchronous code, therefore there's no reason you should get the output you expect

Comment: @JaromandaX in the case I want to get the output I expect, what should I do because I'm not too sure. I want to ensure that the promise is resolved before executing subsequent lines. Because the subsequent lines of code depends on the output of ```let data = await getData();```

Comment: consider using the `promises` version of [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) - i.e. `import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use the `promise` version of `readline`, you can do the following

```
let marker = true;
let promise = Promise.resolve();
rl.on("line", (line) => {
    const fn = async () => {
        console.log(line);
        if (marker) {
            if (line === "START") {
                // call API and wait for data to return before executing other lines in the file
                let data = await getData();
                console.log("Promise resolved", data);
            }
            marker = false;
        } else {
            // read subsequent lines
        }
    };
    promise = promise.then(fn);
});
```